# How to bind SASS plugin goal to tomcat7 deploy phase (maven)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, sass

I am developing a webapp running on Tomcat7, and using maven for dependencies/automated builds. Yesterday I started using the [sass-maven-plugin](https://github.com/Jasig/sass-maven-plugin), which is great. Its goal `sass:update-stylesheets` processes sass files and outputs css. Unfortunately, I can't have it executed during the webapp packaging. I am pretty new to maven too, so I might have missed something. Here's my understanding :

- when I type `mvn tomcat7:deploy`, maven executes the `deploy` goal defined in the tomcat7 plugin
- this plugin goes through some phases of the development lifecycle. More specifically, as mentioned in the [doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html), it "invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase package prior to executing itself."
- if I map the goal sass:update-stylesheets to the package phase in `<build><executions/></build>`, it should be executed everytime I deploy/redeploy my app.

When I run `mvn sass:update-stylesheets` independently of tomcat7:deploy, everything is smooth. sass-maven-plugin gets the .scss files from src/main/resources, processes them and places the output in src/main/webapp/resources, where I want it to be to be deployed with my webapp. Unfortunately, if I don't run the command prior to `tomcat7:deploy`, I don't get any css for my pages. What did I get wrong? Also, is there any way I could map the `sass:update-stylesheets` to the phase `process-resources`, for instance, which would make more sense? Lastly, if this all works, will Eclipse's incremental build pick it up?

Here's my pom.xml (the relevant parts)

```
    ...

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    ...
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- SASS processing -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jasig.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-css</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-stylesheets</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <useCompass>true</useCompass>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <source>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                            </source>
                            <destination>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources</destination>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The correct phase is probably `generate-resources`.

Comment: `pre-package` might be worth a look, too.

Comment: As for Eclipse mapping I googled this - https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2e-jasig-sass-connector/. There is a sample project as well - https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2e-jasig-sass-connector/source/browse/jasig-sass-sample/pom.xml . And you should probably stick to the default phase binding (`process-sources`).

Comment: Anyway, no matter the phase, update-stylesheets is not called. generate-resources was my first choice, but since package was the only one mentioned on the tomcat7 plugin doc I gave it a try. Building at the moment for "pre-package".

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg pre-package didn't work either. I don't even get any output from sass-maven-plugin in the console, that for any phase.

Comment: Tomcat's `deploy` should run `package` which should execute previous phases (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) . Its strange if you don't get your CSS when running `tomcat7:deploy`.

Comment: @Cowcow: That's _really_ strange. To rule out it is an eclipse issue, please run maven manually with the sass processing bound to either `generate-resources` or `pre-package` with debug output. Hint: If two plugins are bound to the same phase, they are executed in order of their appearance in the pom.

Comment: @PavelHoral: Just tried with process-sources, same deal.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: I'm building on two machines, using the exact same revision, and I clean before the build. One does everything through Eclipse, the other one is just : svn update && mvn clean tomcat7:deploy. It is not just that sass-maven-plugin would be called "too late" for packaging, because even afterwards the css files do not appear in src/main/webapp/resources.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: it _is_ strange. And pretty frustrating.

Comment: Damn, reading. You have configured the stuff in the plugin management section. Please move the execution and it's binding to the build section (that is, out of the pluginManagement's plugins section into build's plugins section).

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg nice spot.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: thank you so much. The more you know. I moved it there because Eclipse was throwing an error, but had no idea why the error disappeared or what the difference was. Well, I've got some reading to do! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: At your service. ;) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured the stuff in the plugin management section. Please move the execution and it's binding to the build section (that is, out of the pluginManagement's plugins section into build's plugins section).